# Python linked list remove duplicate

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to remove duplicates from a sorted linked list "head". My code below always returns the last duplicate if the list ends with a duplicate. for e.g. `[1,2,2,3,3]` will return `[1,2,3,3]`. I can't figure out why. Does anyone have an idea?

```
class Solution(object):
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """

        if not head:
            return head

        l1=newhead=ListNode(head.val)
        head=head.next


        while head:
            if head.val!=l1.val:
                l1.next=head
                l1=l1.next
            head=head.next

        return newhead
```

Comment: if you want to remove all duplicates you can always use a `set`

Comment: @Mstaino can you use set operation on linked list

Comment: It looks like you're missing an else in your while-loop. `head` should only become `head.next` when the values don't match, not every turn in the loop.

Comment: @micke tried still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of the leading node of each new value and keep fetching the next node until you get a node with a different value, at which point you assign that node as the next node for the leading node:

```
class Solution(object):
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
        node = head
        while node:
            lead = node
            while node.next and node.next.val == lead.val:
                node = node.next
            node = lead.next = node.next
        return head
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solution**

1. Create a class Node with instance variables data and next.
2. Create a class LinkedList with instance variables head and last_node.
3. The variable head points to the first element in the linked list while last_node points to the last.
4. Define methods append, get_prev_node, remove and display.
5. The method append takes a data item as argument and appends a node with that data item to the list.
6. The method get_prev_node takes a reference node as argument and returns the previous node. It returns None when the reference node is the first node.
7. The method remove takes a node as argument and removes it from the list.
8. The method display traverses the list from the first node and prints the data of each node.
9. Define a function remove_duplicates which takes a linked list as argument and removes duplicates from it.
10. The function remove_duplicates uses two nested loops to remove duplicate nodes.
11. Create an instance of LinkedList, remove duplicate nodes and display the list.

**Program/Source Code**

Here is the source code of a Python program to remove duplicates from a linked list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.last_node = None

    def append(self, data):
        if self.last_node is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
            self.last_node = self.head
        else:
            self.last_node.next = Node(data)
            self.last_node = self.last_node.next

    def get_prev_node(self, ref_node):
        current = self.head
        while (current and current.next != ref_node):
            current = current.next
        return current

    def remove(self, node):
        prev_node = self.get_prev_node(node)
        if prev_node is None:
            self.head = self.head.next
        else:
            prev_node.next = node.next

    def display(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            print(current.data, end = ' ')
            current = current.next


def remove_duplicates(llist):
    current1 = llist.head
    while current1:
        data = current1.data
        current2 = current1.next
        while current2:
            if current2.data == data:
                llist.remove(current2)
            current2 = current2.next
        current1 = current1.next


a_llist = LinkedList()

data_list = input('Please enter the elements in the linked list: ').split()
for data in data_list:
    a_llist.append(int(data))

remove_duplicates(a_llist)

print('The list with duplicates removed: ')
a_llist.display()
```

**Program Explanation**

1. An instance of LinkedList is created.
2. The user is prompted to enter the data items for the list.
3. The function remove_duplicates is called to remove duplicates from the list.
4. The linked list is displayed.